# EC2 RDP from multiple physical locations

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-access, rdp

I'm running windows sever 2012 on EC2 and I have users who RDP in from multiple physical locations-ie. logging on from Mobile hot-spots and home ISPs with dynamic IPs.

For security, I'm working on the AWS security group and wanted to avoid using 0.0.0.0 for inbound RDP source, but not sure if I can specify the wide range of IPs that my users will be using. I have about 3-4 uses at this time.  What would be best way to reduce security risk?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running RDP over an SSH tunnel and/or setup a VPN.

In both cases, you can limit the open RDP port to either the SSH gateway or the VPN network.